# Get react component from library using a list

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list:

```
var coins =["BTC", "ETH","LTC"]
```

And there is a [react library](https://github.com/kirillshevch/react-cryptocoins/tree/master/src/icons) where I can get Icons for these coins using the following schema:

```
<Icon.Eth /> or <Icon.Btc /> or <Icon.ltc />
```

But the list is retrieved using an API and it can change at any moment.
Is there a way to do something like this:

```
<Icon.coins[0] /> or <Icon.coins[1] /> or <Icon.coins[2] />
```

Comment: `<Compoent />` is shorthand for `React.createElement(Component)`. `React.createElement(Icon.coins[1])` should work

Comment: Ah, I see, your question implies there's a coins array, but you were using that as an example. There is no `coins` array. Your question is confusing, are you trying to look up by index, or by the name?

Comment: coinName = coins[I] for whatever index I am in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use square brackets like this

```
let IconA = Icon[coins[0]];
let IconB = Icon[coins[1]];

// Then use them like this
<IconA /> or <IconB />
```

Comment: I tried <Icon[{coinName}] /> and <Icon[coinName] /> and none of them worked. I got Syntax error: Unexpected token

Answer (score 1):

If you want to look up dynamically based on coin name, you can import all coins and look them up by string.

```
import * as Icons from 'react-cryptocoins';

const coins = ['Eth'];

class MyClass extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                { React.createElement(Icons[coins[0]]) }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Note this requires your array to be title cased, not all capitals. Putting it all together, I would make a component for this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import * as Icons from 'react-cryptocoins'

const Coin = ({ icon }) => (
    React.createElement(Icons[coins[0]]) }
);

Coin.propTypes = {
    icon: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};

export default Coin;
```

Usage:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Coin from './Coin';

const coins = ["BTC", "ETH", "LTC"];

function capitalize(str) {
    return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.substr(1).toLowerCase();
}

class MyElement extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                { coins.map( coin => (
                    <Coin icon={capitalize(coin)} />
                )}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I got the following error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.